# Autoresizing tableview cell with fixed subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, autoresize

I want to have a cell with a header with title and switch. When the switch is on, it should show the content expanding the cell with an animation. The header should be always visible and have a constant height.

The cell consists of a container view with 2 subviews, the header, and a body. The body has a label for the cell's content.

The cell has a delegate that tells the controller to reload the content like this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

(Nothing in between. Should I specify something just to be sure?)

I have tried having a height constraint for the header and one for the body and when the switch updates its value, I update the body's constraint to the height of the label (the calculation is being done correctly). I have also tried having a single constraint for the container (constant header height + label height + padding) which also didn't work.

The controller has is the tableView's delegate. I'm not setting a estimated row height (should I?) and for `heightForRowAt` I'm returning `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

If you have any suggestion on how it could be done, even for a different view/subviews organization, please comment.

[image]

**EDIT:**

This was actually a silly mistake. I was updating the constraints after I was calling my delegate cell. For future reference I'm posting here the code.

```
func configure(with reminder: Reminder, delegate: CellUpdateDelegate) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.reminder = reminder

    bodyLabel.text   = reminder.body
    headerTitle.text = reminder.title

    let height = bodyLabel.requiredHeight + 16
    containerHeight.constant = 48 + (alertSwitch.isOn ? height : 0 )
}

@objc func switching() {
    let height = bodyLabel.requiredHeight + 16
    containerHeight.constant = 48 + (alertSwitch.isOn ? height : 0 )
    delegate?.didSelect(reminder)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle the switch event and update the constraint?

Comment: When I was reading it again I found the problem, thanks, buddy.